# Auto-filling/bypassing SED password screen

Tags: linux, encryption, sed

I would like to use a Self-Encrypting Drive in an embedded Linux application, but since it is embedded (i.e. no monitor, keyboard, or mouse), I have no way to enter the password on boot. Is there a way to store the password on this computer such that the OS automatically boots when connected to this set of hardware, but requires a password on a different set of hardware? Perhaps this is possible to do with a USB dongle that stores the password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to store the password on this computer such that the OS automatically boots when connected to this set of hardware, but requires a password on a different set of hardware?

This is usually done by storing the key inside a secure hardware element – in standard PCs this would be the [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module). You can have encryption keys bound just to the TPM itself, or you can have them additionally bound to the exact boot state – see [measured boot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/measured-boot-host-attestation).

Windows BitLocker uses the TPM in exactly this way (and with self-encrypting OPAL drives, too). The same could be applied to Linux, whether LUKS or SED.

Many embedded SoCs have their own secure elements which can store encryption keys bound to that particular chip, though they don't necessarily have an equivalent to TPM's "measured boot".

> Perhaps this is possible to do with a USB dongle that stores the password?

Probably not with any existing products. Even "smart" USB dongles (e.g. FIDO2 keys or PKCS#11 smartcard tokens) have no way to determine whether the hardware has changed or not. At best, they can be protected with another passphrase – but then you're back to exactly the same problem you had in the first place (i.e. needing to store or derive that *new* passphrase in a secure manner).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about something like an ATA password which might trigger the BIOS/UEFI on an x86 PC to prompt for unlocking if it is set as the boot drive.

If that's the case, you might be able to use an additional (USB or not; as long as it can be configured as boot drive on the platform) drive for the `/boot` partition (i.e. bootloader, kernel and initramfs unencrypted), includes `hdparm` in the initramfs and use it to unlock the drive before mounting the "real" root filesystem. Exactly how depends on the early init you / the distro uses.